# JOIN SQL request

Tags: sql, join, request

I have a problem with a join in my sql request.

I have two database :

> - First  : I store images (id, filename)
> - Second : On my website, some users are forbidden to see some images. I also store in this database (id_image, id_user).

If a user doesn't appear in this second database, He s allow to see the image.

Now I would like to have a request which list for an user all images he s allow to see.

That's my actual request (which s wrong).

```
SELECT 
      pi.filename, 
FROM 
    image AS pi
INNER JOIN 
    images_forbidden AS pii
ON 
    pi.id = pii.id_image AND pii.id_user = 10
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join`

```
SELECT pi.filename
FROM image AS pi 
LEFT JOIN images_forbidden AS pii ON pi.id = pii.id_image 
                                 AND pii.id_user = 10
WHERE pii.id_image IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to find images that *don't* match.  A `LEFT JOIN` is one method:

```
SELECT pi.filename, 
FROM image pi LEFT JOIN 
     images_forbidden pii
     ON pi.id = pii.id_image AND pii.id_user = 10
WHERE pii.id_image IS NULL;
```

Another common method would use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT pi.filename
FROM image pi
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM images_forbidden pii
                  WHERE pi.id = pii.id_image AND pii.id_user = 10
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` like

```
SELECT 
      pi.filename
FROM 
    image AS pi
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM images_forbidden 
              WHERE pi.id = id_image 
                    AND id_user = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NOT IN` to achieve this instead of a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  filename
  FROM  image
  WHERE (id NOT IN ( SELECT  id_image
                       FROM  images_forbidden
                       WHERE (id_user = 10)))
```

This code selects all `filename` from the `image` table where the `id` is not in a list of `id_image` for user 10.